# variable stuck in SSIS package

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I am writing my first SSIS package to translate data from an SQL View to a flat text file.

The flat text filename needs to be in the date format "[year][month][day][hour][minute][second][ms].txt".

I have added a script component to generate this name which stores it to a variable `@[User::Filename]` correctly.

[image: SSIS Property Window]

Somehow during fiddling with the Script Task the `ReadWriteVariables` property has been set to the result of the Script (eg. "20130524140500297").

[image: Property Window]

I have tried removing this setting in the property window of the Task and by editing the task:

[image: Edit task window]

This seems to 'take' but when I build the package **the setting magically reverts to the useless number!**

Is there something I am missing or any way to remove this permanently?
I don't want to revert the file to an earlier version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're missing the fact, that `ReadWriteVariables` property in `Script Component` should have a list of variables that you want to modify in your script. You however set it to evaluate as expression :).
To correct this, set `ReadWriteVariables` to `@[User::Filename]`, mark `EvaluateAsExpression` property of `@[User::Filename]`, and set the expression to the variable, not the script.

edit: evaluate variable as expression location:

[image]

Comment: I have set the `ReadWriteVariables` property to the Variable now, however I can't find where to "mark EvaluateAsExpression property of @[User::Filename]" or "set the expression to the variable",, can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: Ok, see the edit. Btw, I don't think you need ExecValueVariable anymore